# JSoup Select Tag Recursive Search

Tags: html, dom, jsoup

I recently tried to work with JSoup to parse HTML documents, I went through the turorial on JSoup and found that the [select-Method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) might be what I am looking for.

What I try to accomplish is to find all elements in a html document which possess a certain class. To test that, I tried this with the amazon web page (idea: find all deals with certain offers).

So I inspected the web page to see which classes and ids are being used and then I tried to integrate this into a small code snippet. In this example I found the follwing element:

```
<span id="dealTitle" class="a-size-base a-color-link dealTitleTwoLine restVisible singleCellTitle autoHeight">PROCAVE Matratzen-Brücke aus Schaumstoff 25 x 200 cm für ...</span>
```

This element is embedded in other elements and exists multiple times (for each deal of course). So here is my code to read the deal elements:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.de/gp/angebote/ref=gbph_ftr_s-8_cd61_page_1?gb_f_LD=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL%252CUPCOMING,dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL,page:1,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:8&pf_rd_p=425ddcb8-bed4-4e85-ac0f-c1a79d14cd61&pf_rd_s=slot-8&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_r=BTHRY008J9N3N5CCMNEN&gb_f_second=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL,dealTypes:COUPON_DEAL,page:8,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:8").timeout(0).get();

            Elements deals = doc.select("span.a-size-base.a-color-link.dealTitleTwoLine.restVisible.singleCellTitle.autoHeight");

            for (Element deal : deals) {
                if (deal.text().contains("ItemMatch")) {
                    System.out.println("Found deal: " + deal.text());
                }
            }
```

Unfortunately I can't get the element I am looking for. *deals* has always the size of 0. I tried to modify my select with only part of the classes, I added the id-attribute and so on. Nevertheless, I do not get the elements (in this case these are nested into some others). If I try an element which is above this element in the DOM hierarchy (e.g. the div with class "a-section a-spacing-none slotContainer"), this is found.

Do I actually need to specify the whole DOM hierarchy (by using ">" in my select expressions? I expected to be able to define a selector and JSoup would travers and search the whole DOM-tree.

Comment: If your question is sufficiently answered, you should consider accepting the best answer and thereby mark this question as solved. If you need further help, please specify exactly what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to specify the full DOM hierarchy. Your test should work, if the elements are really part of the DOM. I suspect that they might not be part of DOM as it is loaded be JSoup. The reason might me, that the inner DOM nodes are filled by JavaScript through AJAX. JSoup does not run JavaScript, so dynamically loaded parts of the DOM are not accessible. To achieve what you want you can either look into the AJAX calls directly and analyze them, or you move on to another solution like selenium webdriver, which runs a real browser including a working JavaScript engine.

Comment: Yep, you are right it is because of JS/AJAX. Thanks for redirecting me to selenium webdriver, I'll try that instead.